# empty MySQL stored procedure not compiling

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below MySQL procedure code flags error at line 1. If I remove the arguments of below stored procedure it compiles fine.

---

```
 DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE test.USER_INPUT(@TITLE VARCHAR(20), @SEVERITY INT, @CLOSEDATE DATETIME)
 BEGIN     
 END
 DELIMITER ;
```

---

what's wrong in the above code? where is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. You are missing a delimiter after `END`
2. Your parameter names contain in invalid character `@`. Either quote the column names, if you want to keep the `@`, or remove it.

What will work is:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test.USER_INPUT(TITLE VARCHAR(20), SEVERITY INT, CLOSEDATE DATETIME)
BEGIN     
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also make sure the database `test` exists.

Comment: actually I want the procedure to take user input. i.e. the character '@'. I tried to do that with the delimiter but could not. Do you know how to achieve this?